# How to minify Laravel .js and .css files

Tags: javascript, css, laravel, minify

I started a web app using Laravel 6 years ago and trying to optimize it and update the technologies around it. I was searching for minifying my .css and .js files (or any minifyable files) without using NPM since I do not have NPM installed in my project and that it is not a Node project.

What are my options?

1. Can I integrate NPM in my project?
2. Is there another way to minify without using NPM?
3. If I integrate NPM in my project, since I did not create my project with NPM, is it easy to do it?

Thanks for helping me out :)

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/mix. Install Nodejs.

Comment: I asume you mean minify automatically (because there are many free web services to minify code). Some code editors (for example phpStorm) have tools for automatically minify libraries. There is a Ruby tools somewhere too.

Comment: I actually use PHP Storm, I didn't know that was an option. But how will I do to minify and say that I want the minified version of my file instead of the original one?

Comment: Laravel 6 was released only some months ago ... If you're using the default Laravel npm commands, `npm run dev`/`npm run watch` will _not_ minify your assets - for debugging purpose. If you run `npm run prod` to compile your assets they will be minified - for production/speed purposes

Comment: The thing is that I'm still with version 5.8 and don't know if I can use NPM for my project. I'm running on a server using Apache2 server on Linux.